# How to monitor android device free space programatically

Tags: android

I want to update and show to the user available free space of my device, I tried many ways but nothing worked, every method I used seemed to show memory only once at app start, but than every call of those methods printed the same value, there was no update
currently I'm using this method

```
public long getfreeMemory() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    return (long) (statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * statFs.getBlockSize());
}

public void checkAppMemory() {
    Log.e("MEMORY", getfreeMemory() + "");
    memoryHandler_.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            checkAppMemory();
        }
    }, (int) (CHECK_MEMORY_FREQ_SECONDS * 1000));
}
```

I just want to detect, when there is no available free storage, I was using BroadCastReceiver, but one device (Samsung s4 os 4.4.2) doesn't fired up memory low event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `getRootDirectory()` is unlikely to change, since that partition is read-only.

If you want to monitor free space, you have to choose a file on the partition that matters to you, such as `getFilesDir()` to find out the free space on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: What if I want to monitor sdcard storage ?

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili: If by "sdcard storage", you mean [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), use `getExternalFilesDir()`. If by "sdcard storage", you mean [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), see if `getExternalFilesDirs()` returns 2+ items, and if it does use the second and subsequent ones.

Comment: Yes, removable storage I tried to use getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() instead but the value doesn't update

Comment: I just want to detect when there is no available storage, I was using  BroadCastReceiver but one device (Samsung s4 os 4.4.2) doesn't fired up memory low event

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili: For removable storage, you need to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (plural). If there are 2+ items in the results, the second and subsequent ones are directories on removable storage.

Answer (score -1):

You can use  this line :

```
getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)
```